# Yodlee getContentServicesByContainerType2 api call not working

Tags: php, yodlee

I got an error while using this getContentServicesByContainerType2 api call in php.
The error is: "Argument value not found: Credits".

[exceptionType] => com.yodlee.core.dataservice.ContainerNotFoundException
[message] => Argument value not found: Credits

But i passed the containerType as "Credits"

Can you please provide need solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please pass containerType as "credits" in lower case? This should work, while we would request you to refer Yodlee [Constants](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Yodlee_Constants) page for other container types. We have corrected the Constant page.